# Mostrar valor de campo data em um listview numa aplicação C#

Tags: c#

Boa noite a todos. Preciso puxar valores de um campo do tipo data (MySQL) e exibir num listview em uma aplicação C#. Acontece que o listview mostra o valor com data e hora, mas preciso que seja exibida apenas a data. Como faço? Grato!

Comment: Mostre o que vc tem feito, seu código.

Comment: ListViewItem CAMPOS = new ListViewItem(READER[0].ToString());
                        CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[1].ToString());
                        CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[2].ToString());
                        CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[3].ToString());
                        CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[4].ToString());

Comment: Apenas para explicar, o ultimo campo é a data de nascimento da pessoa. Essa rotina está dentro de um while, para mostrar todos os registros. Aí na coluna do ListView, onde deveria aparecer apenas a data de nascimento, aparecer a data seguida da hora (sempre 00:00:00)

Comment: Para gravar a data no banco, estou usando essa rotina para pegar o valor num MaskedTextBox e gravar:  string datan = Convert.ToDateTime(MSKDATA.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); Ela é gravada como yyyy-MM-dd, mas ao recuperar em uma consulta, a hora vem junto.

Answer (score 2):

Na hora de adicionar o item ao `listview` você deve formatar a data como queira, caso contrário o resultado será igual ao método `ToString()` que resulta em Data e Hora.

Para formatar a data você tem várias opções, no seu caso de exibir somente a data, pode fazer assim:

considere `data` como a variável do tipo `DateTime`

1= `data.ToShortDateString();`

2= `data.ToString("d");`

3= `data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Para mais formatos veja a documentação do `DateTime.ToString()`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Veja no .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/60syZo

Considerando seu código atual que colocou nos comentários:

```
ListViewItem CAMPOS = new ListViewItem(READER[0].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[1].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[2].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[3].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[4].ToString());
```

E considerando, por exemplo, que sua coluna da data seja a terceira coluna, de índice 2, você pode fazer assim:

```
ListViewItem CAMPOS = new ListViewItem(READER[0].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[1].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER.GetDateTime(2).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[3].ToString()); 
CAMPOS.SubItems.Add(READER[4].ToString());
```

Recomendo que leia sobre padrões de nomenclatura também.

Comment: Acontece que o valor vem de um campo data, direto para um ListView. Criei um objeto do tipo MySqlDataReader, aí pego coluna por coluna e atribuo a uma coluna do ListView. Só que esse valor proveniente de um campo do tipo DATE no MySQL vai com a data e hora

Comment: Para gravar a data no banco, estou usando essa rotina para pegar o valor num MaskedTextBox e gravar: string datan = Convert.ToDateTime(MSKDATA.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); Ela é gravada como yyyy-MM-dd, mas ao recuperar em uma consulta, a hora vem junto.

Comment: coloque o código em que preenche seu listview

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: Vou tentar essa solução. Quantos aos padrões de nomenclatura, não utilizei porque esse projeto é apenas para testes. Agradeço a ajuda e retorno assim que puder.

Comment: Funcionou a solução que me deu. Obrigado. Agradeço também aos outros que ajudaram.

Comment: não se esqueça de marcar como resposta. Obrigado